# How to switch between embedded container from inside one embedded view to another embedded view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have two embedded container overlapping in the same place in one view controller. I made them interchangeable by set the hidden property on the container and use a segment control to set the hidden state of the two embedded container, which I have already made it. What I want now is that how can I show the other embedded container when I toggled a button in one embedded container view. The two embedded views belonged to two different view controller class.  I tried to set the hidden property  when the button on one embedded view is toggled which is set in the parent class to false, it says "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value", it means I didn't initialize the "ChangePersonalInfo" which is the embedded container though the parent view controller is created, so how can I initialize it in order to set the hidden property.
here is my code

```
class MiscellaneousDetailsViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func verifyPhoneNumber(sender: AnyObject) {
        let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MyProfileViewController") as! MyProfileViewController
        vc.ChangePersonalInfo.hidden = false

    }
}

class MyProfileViewController: UIViewController, SMSegmentViewDelegate 
{
    @IBOutlet weak var ChangePersonalInfo: UIView!
} 
// parent view controller
```

Comment: Try this :        let VC = YourViewController()
                      vc.ChangePersonalInfo.hidden = false

Comment: @guru, I tried, not working. the "ChangePersonalInfo"property is still nil

Comment: can you provide some more info about  MyProfileViewController

Comment: @guru, ok I edited my question

Answer (score 0):

You need to hide you view in viewDidload mathod of viewcontroller because this mathod called when your view load and set  the default property of view ,
  by default the view's visible property is  true

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

if (isViewHidden == true)
{ ChangePersonalInfo?.hidden = true

}



    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}`
```

Mantain one boolean var for setting hidden true/false

```
 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!)      {
    let  nextScene =  segue.destinationViewController as! MyProfileViewController
    nextScene.isViewHidden = true
```

}

Comment: Thanks for answering. I still have some questions. What I need to do is when I pressed the button in  MiscellaneousDetailsViewController, the MyProfileViewController's ChangePersonalInfo hidden property change to false, so what should I do with the @IBAction func verifyPhoneNumber(sender: AnyObject)